# ionic2 app not responding when push notification subscribed by topics

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

Im using ionic2 to implement the push notification.(https://firebase.google.com/)

using device registration id, I'm  able to receive the notification.but if i subscribe any topics ,on loading of the app the app is crashing(app error on real hardware : unfortunately,push-app is stopped,android 5+)

tried checking issue using chrome console : But not error or exception
(chrome://inspect/#devices)

implementation has been done based on below post:

https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.tis93ojyf

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
--
--
let pushObj = Push.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "343415024673",
          sound: true,
          vibrate: true,     
          clearNotifications: true,
          topics: ['/topics/global']
        },
        ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: true,
          sound: 'true'
        },
        windows: {}
      });
});
```

Thanks in advance